# Can't seem to find why " 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference " is null, what am I missing here

Tags: java, android

So the problem lays in Activity 2, however I will post both activity1 and activity2. I read through a few other questions and all of which seemed to be missing an editText of some sort, I've looked and looked and can't seem to find where I'm missing one getting initialized for the life of me. Could someone please help me spot where this is, it absolutely killing me. Error message I recieve when clicking the submit button is in the title, it says its happening on line 23 of Activity 2, which is the line reading "intent.putExtra("editText", editText.getText().toString());"

I feel like this is an easy fix but its just stumping me hard.
All help is appreciated! Thank you.

**Activity 1**

```
package com.example.ndagenai.first_activity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class FirstActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private int mRequestCode = 100;

TextView textView;

private Jokes[] mList = new Jokes[]{
    new Jokes (R.string.joke_text0),
    new Jokes (R.string.joke_text1),
    new Jokes (R.string.joke_text2),
    new Jokes (R.string.joke_text3),
    new Jokes (R.string.joke_text4),
};

@Override
//creates activity
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_first);

    Button nextB = findViewById(R.id.nextButton);
    nextB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, mRequestCode);
        }
    });

    Button b0 = findViewById(R.id.button0);
    b0.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.category);
            textView.setText(R.string.joke_text0);
        }
    });
    Button b1 = findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.category);
            textView.setText(R.string.joke_text1);
        }
    });

    Button b2 = findViewById(R.id.button2);
    b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.category);
            textView.setText(R.string.joke_text2);
        }
    });
    Button b3 = findViewById(R.id.button3);
    b3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.category);
            textView.setText(R.string.joke_text3);
        }
    });
    Button b4 = findViewById(R.id.button4);
    b4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.category);
            textView.setText(R.string.joke_text4);
        }
    });
}
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode == mRequestCode && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        String editTextString = data.getStringExtra("editText");
    }
}
}
```

**Activity 2**

```
package com.example.ndagenai.first_activity;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class SecondActivity extends Activity {
EditText editText;

@Override //makes activity for second one
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

    Button b = findViewById(R.id.SubmitButton);
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.putExtra("editText", editText.getText().toString());
            setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
            finish();
        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: You mean in activity 2 where it's declared but never initialized?

Answer (score 0):

In activity2 you have

```
EditText editText;
```

But you don’t have a

```
editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextId);
```

So you’re assigning a variable that never gets pointed to anything

Comment: Honestly, Thank you so much, I've been working on this far too long and this lead into my next thing which was completely unrelated but I finished my project now. Kudos to you for finding my dumb mistake due to working on this for almost 6 hours straight.. lol.